# Mac OSX: Switch to Python 2.7.3

Tags: python, macos, version, python-2.7, command-line-interface

I've installed the [Mac OSX Python 2.7.3](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.3/), and tried switching to the new version:

```bash
$ python2.7 -V
Python 2.7.3         # It was installed
$ python -V
Python 2.6.1         # Default is 2.6
$ export VERSIONER_PYTHON_VERSION=2.5
$ python -V
Python 2.5.4         # I can switch to 2.5
$ export VERSIONER_PYTHON_VERSION=2.6
$ python -V
Python 2.6.1         # And 2.6
```

But:

```
$ export VERSIONER_PYTHON_VERSION=2.7
$ python -V
python: VERSIONER_PYTHON_VERSION environment variable error (ignored)
Python 2.6.1
```

Can't switch to 2.7! Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The python.org install will put a python executable in /usr/local/bin . Apple's python is in /usr/bin

To call the python.org python you can use its full path /usr/local/bin/python or change your path to put /usr/local/bin before /usr/bin. You will still be able to call Apple's python by using its full path /usr/bin/python

Some python installs e.g. Macports provide a tool that provides symbolic links to various python installs and allows you to switch between them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we can switch the python version on the Mac OS X without resorting to something like `MacPorts` or `ActivePython`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because VERSIONER_PYTHON_VERSION is specific to python packages built by apple.

Comment: So which package should I download?

Comment: Whichever package you'd like. You can set PATH environment variable appropriately in order to use a specific version of python by `python`. FYI, macports also has a mechanism for prioritize a particular version of python(install python_select package).

Comment: Is there an official Apple Python 2.7.3 package?

Comment: I don't think there is. The lion(10.7) has Python 2.7.1 bundled from the start.