# Confused about why my python (on Mac) automatically updates to 2.7.3

Tags: python, macos

I'm using a Mac 10.6.8 computer and, before today, whenever I started up the terminal and typed "python" it would tell me I was using python 2.6.1, even though I had already installed 2.7.3 from Python.org a few months ago:

```
cd
python
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49)
```

So I searched online to see how I could change to Python 2.7.3 when using the python interpreter. I installed it from Python.org and according to this question ( [Mac OSX: Switch to Python 2.7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445666/mac-osx-switch-to-python-2-7-3) ) the default locations of Apple and Python.org's python differ. I then moved to where Python.org python was located and simply typed python:

```
cd /usr/local/bin
python 
Python 2.7.3 (v2.7.3:70274d53c1dd, Apr  9 2012, 20:52:43)
```

Everything's as expected, since python should call the version that's in its directory first. I closed the old terminal and opened a new window, so I'm back at my home directory. But this time when I use python, I see that I'm back at 2.7.3.

```
cd
python
Python 2.7.3 (v2.7.3:70274d53c1dd, Apr  9 2012, 20:52:43)
```

This is what I wanted, but I'm *confused as to why this worked*. All I did was I went to the place where 2.7.3 was located and typed "python." I didn't change any variables, do the changes reflected here ( https://superuser.com/questions/35256/how-can-i-change-the-default-python-version-on-snow-leopard ) or here ( [how to change default python version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846167/how-to-change-default-python-version) ), alter my bash files, etc. so why did my actions above make the default python suddenly switch to 2.7.3?

Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Is right - Mac != Windows.  It will use `$PATH`, so everything is not as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just typing `python` by itself will not load the python from the local directory. It'll be looked up in your `$PATH` environment variable instead. Use `./python` to invoke a binary in the local directory.

That means that your second `python` call *already* was different from the first; the Python installer must have added the new location to your `PATH` variable (usually via `.bashrc` or similar shell startup construct).

Use `/usr/bin/python` to run the Mac OS X default, or use `python2.6` to look up a python binary by version.

Comment: Okay, I went to my folder with 2.6 and ./python does call 2.7.3 as expected, then. The updated PATH variable is in my .bash_profile so I assume that my second call forced that addition into my .bash_profile (originally it didn't have that, when I checked a week ago). I have no idea why it did it, though. I guess it's automatic?

Comment: @DSeita: The .bash_profile update isn't loaded until you open a new Terminal session; perhaps you installed Python while you had a terminal open already?